# One click deployment using scripts

Tags: powershell, web-deployment

I want to deploy a web solution for local server using one click deployment using powershell or any other scripts.
Can any one share any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Powershell can be use in conjunction with [Psake](https://github.com/psake/psake) which is a DSL that allows you to script up deployments (or basically anything really) with a dependency chain. It also abstracts MSDeploy to some extent, making it easier to roll out installs to IIS. Note that MSDeploy can also be used completely independently for relatively simple deployments (such as web sites without any reliance on messaging queues, databases, supporting services, etc.)

Other automated approaches include the likes of [Octopus Deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/) which works by having a central management node push out installations to 'agents' installed on target machines.

Both approaches require you to write your app in a reasonably deployable manner (e.g. having suitably transformable configurations files)

Does that help? There are a number of other options out there but these should help to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Also check http://psappdeploytoolkit.codeplex.com/ (seems to be what you want)
and maybe https://github.com/mislav/git-deploy or https://github.com/p-blomberg/Web-app-deploy-script

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach... this is not the compete but will help you in moving one click direction..

http://ravisoftltd.wordpress.com/2014/04/08/one-click-deployment-with-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to deploy from `MSBUILD`-files (so something like asp or MVC), I would like to point you to [Package-Web](http://sedodream.com/2011/12/24/PackageOncePublishAnywhere.aspx).

It still has some [minor flaws](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17858830/2186023) (which can be worked around pretty easily), but works pretty good.
Only downside that I know of: you have to prepare your project by installing a nuget-package (or get those files into your build process some other way)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a powershell script with something like

```
[string] $package = "solution.wsp"
stsadm -o addsolution -filename $package
stsadm -o deploysolution -name $package -immediate -allowGacDeployment
```